# Launch two processes and return first process to the foreground so it can be killed with ctrl-c

Tags: bash, process

I am launching two processes in a bash script:

> run_webserver
>
> xdg-open http://$(hostname)/dev-environment

The run_webserver is an ongoing process, so I need to be able to kill it with ctrl-c. The xdg-open command simply launches a page in the browser.
If I separate these commands with an ampersand (&), the second process takes away "focus" from the first and I can no longer kill it with ctrl+c... must instead look it up in `ps` and run `kill -9`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

&(Ampersand) sends the process to the background. It means if you run "run_webserver &" then this process will run in the backgrond.

You can bring this process to foreground by looking at the job id for the process in the terminal.

**Steps to bring the process to foreground and kill**

1. jobs :--> this command will list all the process running on the terminal.
2. fg  :--> this command will bring the process to the foreground.

Then you can use your ctrl-c to kill the process, or any other sequence which kills the process.

Please find the attached screen shots:-

[image]

[image: Pressing q helped me quit the process]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without manually checking jobs? I tried running it as follows and I get the error "fg: no job control": `run_webserver & xdg-open http://$(hostname)/dev-environment && fg %1`

Comment: if you're sure that these are the only two processes running on the terminal , i.e  a) run_webserver b) xdg-open http://$(hostname)/dev-environment then you can also use kill -15 %<job-id>. In our case run-webserver would have job-id 1 and 2nd process would have job-id:2.  In that way you don't need to issue jobs command. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a trap to kill the background process on exit, and wait for the background process.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill $!' EXIT
run_webserver &
xdg-open "http://$HOSTNAME/dev-environment"
wait
```

Alternatively, run the other command in the background instead

```
#!/bin/bash

xdg-open "http://$HOSTNAME/dev-environment" &
run_webserver
```

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Answer (score 1):

`fg` will return the most recent process to the foreground. `fg -` will return the penultimate process to the foreground.

Also, you should only use `kill -9` as a last resort, after everything else has failed, because SIGKILL (-9) doesn't permit the program to do any cleanup before exiting. First, just send `kill` by itself, which is equivalent to `kill -TERM`. If that fails after waiting a while, send SIGHUP: `kill -HUP`. Only after those signals fail should you try SIGKILL.