# Why applications do not always run in foreground when started from terminal?

Tags: command-line, process

If I start an application from terminal normally it runs in the foreground. So it is possible to suspend the application (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>), look to the `jobs` and put it back to foreground again with `fg` (similar described at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/172667/265974).

But if I start an application first with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then start another instance of this application from the terminal, this instance will not run in foreground and I cant find it with the `jobs` command. Is it possible to set this application to foreground even if it is not find with `jobs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications check to see if an existing instance is running and if there is, will just open a new window under the remote process.

This is not always the case (Dolphin, KDE's file browser, is stoicly not), and in some cases there are ways to circumvent this in some applications too (Firefox has a `-no-remote` option which can be useful when starting another instance of Firefox in another profile) but this is not guaranteed.

The behaviour is really down to the individual application.